# Addresing a span with a specific class in a list using an array

Tags: jquery

I have a list with three spans each with different class name. Using a button named "Shift" I am trying to toggle only the span with class name "letter" so that it displays either lowercase or uppercase.

So far I can toggle the span with class named "letter" but it is not getting 
the right character from the arrays lowerCase/upperCase.

here is a jsfiddle to show what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/elMed/1qh9ggx5/1/.

your help is much appreciated.

html:

```
<ul id="theList">
    <li class="element ">
        <span class="number">1</span>        
        <span class="letter">q</span>
        <span class="symbol">!</span>       
    </li>
    <li class="element ">
       <span class="number">2</span>
       <span class="letter">w</span>
       <span class="symbol">&quot;</span> 
    </li>     
</ul>
<br>
<input type="button" id="theShift" value="Shift">
```

script:

```
  var lowerCase = ['q', 'w', 'e'];
  var upperCase = ['Q', 'W', 'E'];
  var isShift = false; 

  //start
      $("#theShift").click(function () {
          if (isShift) {
            $('#theList>li').find('span.letter').each(function(){
              $(this).text(lowerCase[$(this).index()]);

            }); 
          }
          else {
            $('#theList>li').find('span.letter').each(function(){
              $(this).text(upperCase[$(this).index()]);

            }); 
          }
          isShift = !isShift;  
     });
  //end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#theShift").click(function () {
      if (isShift) {
        $('#theList>li').find('span.letter').each(function(){
            var val = $(this).text();
            var indexVal = $.inArray(val, upperCase);
            if(indexVal != -1){
                $(this).text(lowerCase[indexVal]);
            }
        }); 
      }
      else {
        $('#theList>li').find('span.letter').each(function(){
            var val = $(this).text();
            var indexVal = $.inArray(val, lowerCase);
            if(indexVal != -1){
                $(this).text(upperCase[indexVal]);
            }
        }); 
      }
```